# How to choose VLC QT interface profile from command line

Tags: qt, command-line, command-line-arguments, vlc

I have custom profiles set up in VLC for the qt layout to use.

I know I can specify the qt interface using `vlc --intf qt`, but I would like to be able to specify the interface profile as well from the command line.

[image: vlc profile selection]

I can't find any mention of how to do this in the [documentation about modules](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/) or the [documentation about the qt interface itself](https://wiki.videolan.org/Qt_Interface/).

How can I specify the profile to use from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible. This may be worth a try

```
     --extraintf=<string>       Extra interface modules
          You can select "additional interfaces" for VLC. They will be launched
          in the background in addition to the default interface. Use a colon
          separated list of interface modules. (common values are "rc" (remote
          control), "http", "gestures" ...)
      --control=<string>         Control interfaces
          You can select control interfaces for VLC.
```

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

Comment: As of today, `--control` doesn't seems to work with latest vlc version (I have tried with my custom profile but nothing changed). Any idea on how to achieve this?